# Python -printing the sql statement record count in the log file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently using the python program for inserting the record and i am using the below statement.The issue is i am trying to print the no of of record inserted in the log file but it is printing only 0 but i can see the inserted record count in the console while running the program Can you help me to print the record count in the log file

Also i  know that  redirecting the python program to > file can have the record count but i want to bring all the details in the same log file after the insert record statement is done as i am using loop for different statement.

```
log="/fs/logfile.txt"

log_file = open(log,'w')

_op = os.system('psql ' + db_host_connection + ' -c "insert into emp select * from emp1;"')

print date , "printing" , _op
```

Comment: `os.system` returns the exit code for the procedure you run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably switch to a "proper" python module for postgresql interactions.
Haven't used postgresql in python before, but one of the first search engine hits leads to:
http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html

You could then do something along the following lines:

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres")

# create a cursor for interaction with the database
cursor = conn.cursor()
# execute your sql statement
cursor.execute("insert into emp select * from emp1")

# retrieve the number of selected rows
number_rows_inserted = cursor.rowcount

# commit the changes 
conn.commit()
```

This should also make things significantly faster than using an `os.system` call(s), especially if you're planning to execute multiple statements.

Comment: :Thx but i would like to do in the os.sytem. Do you have any ways of doing that ?